# How to know when all child components are loaded in vue.js

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vue-resource, vue-component

I have a vue.js app where there are several child components like this:

```
<main-app>
   <child-component></child-component>
   <child-component></child-component>
   <child-component></child-component>
...
</main>
```

When the page is loaded, I can use `ready` hook to know that the components are done loading. Now, these components are filled using ajax data and they can be manually updated by clicking a button. I can get data from each child-component by using `broadcast` and `dispatch` methods. But I want to show the user a preloader when s/he clicks on the button and hide it when all ajax requests are finished. For this I need to know that all child-components are finished loading. Which I cannot do for last 4-5 hours. Google and SO didn't help much.

I have also tried using jQuery's `ajaxStop` but it doesn't seem to work with vue-resource. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do something similar once and what I ended up doing (besides using [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/api/#v-cloak) to display the app once vue rendering is done) was tracking whether each require variable in `data` already had data (or not) and only then, "display" the app (for this I used an internal flag to control whether to display the app or a loading message).

It was something similar to this (this uses underscore.js):

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        data1: [],
        data2: [],
        data3: []
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.showApp();

        // Data 1
        $.getJSON('/path-to/data1', function(data) {
            app.$set('data1', data);
            app.showApp();
        });

        // Data 2
        $.getJSON('/path-to/data2', function(data) {
            app.$set('data2', data);
            app.showApp();
        });

        // Data 3
        $.getJSON('/path-to/data3', function(data) {
            app.$set('data3', data);
            app.showApp();
        });
    },
    methods: {
        showApp: function() {
            // Check if all data was loaded
            var requiredData = _.every(['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], function(el) {
                return _.size(this[el]) > 0;
            }, this);

            // If it was, enable the app
            if (requiredData) {
                $(this.$els.loading).hide();
                $(this.$els.app).fadeIn();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Since you are using components, you will have to use events to fire the `showApp` method on the main app.

Comment: My problem is that I have unknown number of child components inside the main component. In your case I see you have three cases, I suppose. How may I approach in my case?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you will have to do a bit more of work, maybe you can "register" each component with the main app (via component `ready`) to let him know the component is "downloading" data and then use events to signal the main app that the component is done? On main app you can walk through the registered components and check if each component is done downloading and then "display" the app.

Comment: Nice! I have already made changes to signal the main-app that the child-components are downloading data. But how can I know that _all_ the child-components have finished downloading data? Let me rephrase: how to know an *unknown* number of child-components have finished downloading data? Since ajax requests are asynchronous, I am left with no option to know that. (All of the requests fire at the same time).

Comment: Well when you register the component the initial state would be "downloading" or whatever logic works best for you, when it is done downloading, it would fire an event letting the main app know it is done downloading, on main app you check on every event if all components are done downloading, makes sense?

Comment: Thanks! That's great. 

I have one last question, how to know how many child components are there?

Comment: When you register the component you could add them to an array in the main app, from there you can do a components.length to know how many components registered with the main app

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I wanted!