# Vue.js run code when all components are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, vue.js, vue-router

#### Setup

I have a site with an index.html similar to this (using routing):

```
<main-menu></main-menu>
<router-view></router-view>
<footer-menu><footer-menu>
```

I'd like to register some jQuery plugins in all three of those components (from the materialize.css library) and have them functioning as the user clicks around the site.

**edit:** To be clear, this is not an issue with getting jQuery to work, I've used jQuery extensively and if I hit f12 and run the initialization functions, everything works fine.  The problem here is figuring out when Vue.js is done messing with the DOM.

#### What I've tried

*note:* `ready: function() {}` won't work because I'm using routing and the plugins need to work even if the users goes from home -> browse -> home.

Taken from their [documentation](http://router.vuejs.org/en/pipeline/activate.html)

```
route: {
    activate: (transition) => {
        transition.next();
        // Plugins here
    }
}
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363294/vue-js-router-run-code-when-component-is-ready) SO post

```
route: {
    activate() {
        this.$nextTick(function() {
            // Plugins here
        });
    }
}
```

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374149/how-to-know-when-all-child-components-are-loaded-in-vue-js) post however I have an unknown number of components in each of the three top level components and I don't think that manually registering them all is a very good idea

#### What I'm Expecting to Happen

I'd like to see all of my jQuery plugins from all of my components functioning on any given page the user hits regardless of how many times they jump around.

Comment: You need to import the libraries in your main js file. Then all your components should be able to use the libraries.

Comment: the problem isn't so much getting the components to use the library as much as it is figuring out when to call the initialization function for the plugin after vue has finished messing with the dom.

Comment: For jQuery you might need something like this

`window.$ = require('jquery')`

then you can use `$` anywhere in your JS

Comment: The problem isn't getting jQuery to work at all, the issue is figuring out when Vue.js is done messing with the DOM.  If I run the initialization functions manually (after the DOM is done being messed with), everything works just fine

Comment: Vue.js does not mess up the DOM afaik

Comment: It most certainly does when you're using routing (which I am).  That's how it changes pages, it rearranges the stuff in the DOM.  On top of that, any databinding you do will mess with the DOM every time you change something.

Comment: Also, if you use the moustache syntax, that's all DOM manipulation stuff.  Because Vue.js is all client-side, everything has to be DOM manipulations or else nothing would work.  Unlike PHP or C# or something similar, we aren't using a server to build up a page and then send a static file to the browser, instead, the browser is given all the logic and handles shifting everything around.  This method allows users navigate a website, even without an internet connection as the page never has to do a second HTTP request.

Comment: I have been using routing as well. It does not mess up the DOM, any `{{}}` I used, this only will change. :/ Can you provide a poc please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121964/discussion-between-dlkulp-and-mei).